# How to build audacity app source code for Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, audacity

I downloaded the audacity source code from
http://code.google.com/p/audacity/downloads/detail?name=audacity-fullsrc-1.3.13-beta.tar.bz2&can=2&q=

I have to build my app on Mac OS X 10.6 & for Xcode 3.2.5.

I tried by following the steps from 'compile.txt' file in audacitysourceCodeFolder/mac/

But no success.

Can anyone please help me out in installing this.
As I need to study the waveform generation code for a compressed file.

Comment: Why don't you ask on the Audacity mailing list ?

Comment: I checked that out http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=52237  But wasn't able to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
/Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/configure
```

Says:

```
configure: error: pkg-config is required to compile audacity!
```

Download an install MacPorts:

```
http://www.macports.org/install.php
```

Install pkgconfig

```
sudo port install pkgconfig
```

Run again:

```
/Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/configure
```

Says:

```
lib-widget-extra is required to build audacity. A copy is included in the audacity source distribution at lib-src/lib-widget-extra/.
```

Build and install lib-widget-extra:

```
cd /Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/lib-src/lib-widget-extra 
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Run again:

```
/Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/configure
```

Says:

```
configure: error: must have Ogg installed!
```

Install libogg

```
sudo port install libogg
```

Run:

```
 /Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/configure --with-portmixer=no
```

Build:

```
cd /Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/
sudo make install
```

For additional information check:
http://forum.audacityteam.org/ 
http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=55176

Comment: When I do the last step ,cd /Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/
make , then I get 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Provide the prefix to `configure` like this: `/Users/Anne/Desktop/audacity-src-1.3.13-beta/configure --with-portmixer=no prefix=/Users/Anne/Desktop/build/`.